# sending mail with attachment in c++? (or How do I construct a MIME encoded email message that I can send to SMTP?)

Tags: c++, windows, smtp, mime, attachment

is it possible to do it without any third-party lib.

i can send mail to gmail with a simple socket functions. 
i can send files one computer to another too. But i need to send with attachment to any mail account...

can it be done with smtp?

(i searched in here but the answers, that i looked, are not in c++ or not on windows or not open source completely. Sorry if there is/are answer(s) that given before, but i couldn't find )

thanks,

Comment: Why do you want to not use third-party libraries?

Comment: first it must be totaly open source. Many of them are compiled...

and secondly, some new features can be needed in future. i don't want to be depended...
i have enough time to search for now...

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely yes.

As far as SMTP is concerned, you just provide it with the appropriate headers (the [rfc822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc822.html) is out of date, but is a good start) and then the message body, which can be anything.

You probably want to create a message body that is a MIME encoded message describing the text of the email and any attachments.

The question you should be asking is:

> How do I construct a MIME encoded email message that I can send to SMTP?

Also, the problem of creating email messages and sending them has been solved so many times, you should really consider using a library if you're at all able to.

Comment: "How do I construct a MIME encoded email message that I can send to SMTP?"

Yes that is the true question...